# authorizationservice causing unittest fail

Tags: c#, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, authorization, wcf-ria-services

I'm currently learning how to unit test my methods in a silverlight RIA project. I have some methods that the user is authorized. I though I could solve this problem by creating a mock authorizationservice. And then have the user be authorized in that way, but it seems that I a nullreference from the code because it calls the authorizationservice in the project from which the code I'm testing originates, and gets the nullreference in the createdefaultuser method, which I had otherwise manually overridden in the mockauthorizationservice.

How do I get about this?
My mockauthorization has this namespace/class definitionnamespace

```
Notlr.Test
    {
        public class MockAuthentication : AuthenticationService
        {
        }
    }
```

My Ria authenticationservice looks like this:

```
    namespace Notlr.Web
    {
        using System;
        using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
        using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ApplicationServices;
        using System.Web.Security;

        /// <summary>
        /// RIA Services DomainService responsible for authenticating users when
        /// they try to log on to the application.
        ///
        /// Most of the functionality is already provided by the base class
        /// AuthenticationBase
        /// </summary>
        [EnableClientAccess]
        public class AuthenticationService : AuthenticationBase<User>
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jakob, it sounds like you have namespace issues.  Remember that your "test project" in Visual Studio is a Project like any other.  It has its own namespace and compiles into its own .net assembly.  Having a "test project" does not automatically put the mock objects into the tests; you must write the code to accomplish this on your own.

You need to make sure that you're writing the test code to use the mock authorizationservice when the test runs.  If you would like more specific help, please post the code that you're having a problem with.

Comment: I tried to edit my post, I hope the code I've posted is what you request, please guide me along the right path. Should my test be in Notlr.Test ??